# Is there anything special about the children of the Solars?

Tags: exalted-3e

In Exalted 3e, each of the major types of exalted that I have the books for has at least a chance of passing on supernatural traits to their children, except apparently the Solars.

The children of the Dragon-blooded have a chance of being Dragon-blooded themselves. The children of Lunars are often Moon-Touched with a variety of possible powers including possible limited transformation (Lunars, p. 18). The children of Sidereals are Star-Blessed and might inherit a small amount fate-related magic (Sidereals Compiled Draft, p. 12).

But if the Solars have anything equivalent I have not found it. Was this a deliberate omission and there is nothing inherently special about the children of Solars, or did I perhaps miss something?

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, but if the stats on [the wiki](https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/Solar_Exalted#Attributes) are correct, for all but Dragon-blooded, the chance is basically nil anyway; there are a fixed (or close to fixed) number of each type of Celestial Exalted (100-200 Solars, 300 Lunars, and a similar number of Sidereal) that reincarnate over and over, and the sum total of *all* of them is maybe 700. Dragon-blooded don't have a limit on their numbers, and there are 10K or so of them, and no limitation on having more.

Comment: @ShadowRanger The chance of the child of an non-dragon-blooded exalted actually exalting is close to nil as you describe, but at least as I read the descriptions it seems that  a fairly large percentage of the children of Lunars or Siderreal will inherit a small amount of power as Moon-Touched / Star-Blessed, though its a little vague on the exact percentages.

Comment: @Jack Thank you for the edits.

Comment: I’m struggling to find supporting evidence enough to write up a full answer, but it does seem third edition assumes most children of Solars are just regular mortals. Less because there’s something special about them, and more that there’s something special about DBs, Lunars and Sidereals in particular. Previous editions had high Essence Solars capable of having God-Blooded children, but there’s very little about children in the third editions books beyond what you describe.

Comment: @GuybrushMcKenzie Fair enough. Perhaps the answer is that its just unaddressed and it's presently unclear in 3e. I doubt it will ever happen, but I would love to see a solar companion book to address things like this, expand on solar circle sorcery, etc.